# How can I delete certain lines with specific extensions in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to delete certain lines from my file right now the file is just a bunch of links that have certain endings (`.unitypackage`, `.anim`, `.png`). I'm trying to remove all lines that have the ending `.anim` but its also deleting lines that contain the word `Animation` instead of the exact ending `.anim`.

I'm currently using `(?-s)^.*.anim.*\R` and replacing with `\1\n`. I have *Match case* enabled, *Wrap around* enabled, and am using *Regular expression*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [dot in regex matches *every* character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989661/4751173), so you have to escape it with a backslash. I don't have access to Notepad++ right now, but an easy solution is to find `^.*\.anim$` (the `$` indicates the end of the line) and replace it with nothing. The disadvantage may be that this leaves empty lines instead of removing them.

An advanced option is to find `\n.*?\.anim\r` instead. The `?` is there to make sure the `\n` of the previous line is matched, otherwise it will match more than one line. You do need to check the '. matches newline' option:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much that saved me so much time Cheers